# XAMPP working together with IIS

Tags: iis, dns, xampp, virtualhost, cname

I have a NAS at home (Windows Server 2012) which I've been using the last few months for hosting my own website. Before that, I had the Windows Essentials role server installed with the remote web access on (wich requires from IIS) but I had to turn it down because my last processor couldn't handle it.

Now I've changed it, I want to set it all up in the cleanest way, but there's no way I can make it work.

As far as I'm concerned, It´s easier to change the Apache´s ports than IIS ones so I changed them to 8079 and 8443. My new ISP provider doesn´t offer static IP so I´m using dynu as a dynamic DNS service.

I set a virtualhost with the following values:

```
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:8079

<VirtualHost *:8079>
   DocumentRoot "C:\xampp183\htdocs\mywebsite"
   ServerName mywebsite.com
   ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The firewall and my router are configured properly (I can reach my default gateway through "dnsname.dynu.com") but when I go to the domain.com control panel and I try to set "dnsname.dynu.com" as a private server throws an error. I redirected the 80 port to 8079 at the dynu's control panel but keeps throwing the error.

I guess the next step is configuring a CNAME pointing to my serverAlias but I can't make it work and I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks!